# Find properties of Image and comparing with origin image using Python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, difference

I am very new to matlab and python, please help me with my queries

1.input the image to the code

2.apply some filtering to the image

3.extract the numerical features from the output image like --->

1. Major and Minor Axis
2. Eccentricity, Perimeter
3. Roundness, Compactness etc.

Also, compare the above data with original Image, and display the output.

Comment: This is way too broad question to answer. Please refer docs or books. find docs for opencv python here : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html

Comment: @SquareRoot17 thank u for the line which has information about only Filtering , but could you suggest Link for Features extraction (above mention) of the image

Comment: These are known as contour features and properties. You might want to know contours first before finding these, but anyway, here you go : Contour features : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html , Contour properties : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what is meant by # 1 - Input image to the code. Are you trying to read image using python / matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
img=imread("sampleimg.jpg");
```

Applying filter:

```
img=medfilt2(img);
```

*This function applies a median filter on the input image*

Extracting features:

```
stats = regionprops('table',img,'centroid','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
```

*This function 'regionprops' gives the details about the objects in a Black and White images their centroids and Axises lenghts.*